# Alternative proof for $\left|\frac{a}b+\frac{b}a\right|\ge 2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, alternative-proof

> Let $K$ an ordered field and $a,b\in K\setminus\{0\}$. Prove that $\left|\frac{a}b+\frac{b}a\right|\ge 2$.

I give my proof but I want to know if there exist a more simple proof than that:

1) Note that $ab^{-1}ba^{-1}=1$. Then we can rewrite the inequality as $|c+c^{-1}|\ge 2$.

2) As $cc^{-1}=1>0$ then by the second axiom of order for an ordered field we know that if $c>0$ then $c^{-1}>0$. Other useful facts are

- $-b=(-1)b$
- $(-1)^2=1$
- $a(-1)=(-1)a$
- $|c^{-1}|=|c|^{-1}$

Then if $c<0$ this implies that $c^{-1}<0$. Then we can rewrite the inequality as

$$|c^{-1}c(c+c^{-1})|=|c^{-1}(c^2+1)|=|c^{-1}|(c^2+1)=|c|^{-1}(c^2+1)\ge 2$$

$$c^2+1\ge|c|2\to |c|2=|c|+|c|=2|c|\to c^2-2|c|+1\ge 0$$

Now if $c<0$ we have that $|c|=-c$ then

$$(-c)^2+2c+1=c^2+2c+1=(c+1)^2\ge 0\tag{1}$$

and for $c>0$ we similarly have that

$$c^2-2c+1=(c-1)^2\ge 0\tag{2}$$

Because $(1)$ and $(2)$ are true then the proof is complete.

**My question:** I searched a different proof that dont use the fact $x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$ but I dont found something simpler but I *feel* that it must exist something simpler. This is the reason why I opened this question. Maybe Im wrong but... who knows!

Comment: Could you make a slick proof with geometric series? Suppose $c>0$ and let $c = 1 + d$. If $d \geq 1$, then we're done:
$$ 1+d+(1+d)^{-1}\geq 1+d\geq 2. $$
If $d < 1$, then
$$ 1 + d + \frac{1}{1+d} = 1 + d + (1 - d + d^2 - d^3 + d^4 - \cdots) = 2 + d^2 - d^3 + \cdots > 2 $$ I think this should work formally, but I don't trust my intuition with general ordered fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If
$|c+\frac1{c}| < 2$,
then, squaring,
$c^2+2+\frac1{c^2} < 4$
or
$c^2-2+\frac1{c^2} < 0$
or
$(c-\frac1{c})^2 < 0$.

A contradiction.

Is this simple-minded proof correct?

Comment: Its fine... but I wanted something more simpler, something of the kind $c+c^{-1}\ge 1+1$ and different manipulations without the use of any square (if possible). But, well, it seems that some square is unavoidable.

Comment: Maybe even simpler: a direct proof. $\big(c+\tfrac{1}{c}\big)^2 = \big(c-\tfrac{1}{c}\big)^2 + 2^2 \ge 2^2$.

Comment: A nicer reformulation.